# Vues.js . async/await not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await

Even if this methods seels to be running correctly , the console log shows that the final RESULt is output before the inned await/sync

```
    submitForm: function() {
      console.log("SUBMIT !");
      // vee-validate form validation request
      const makeValidationRequest = () => {
        return this.$validator.validateAll();
      };
      const validateAndSend = async () => {
        const isValid = await makeValidationRequest();
        console.log("form validated... isValid: ", isValid);
        if (isValid) {
          console.log("VALID FORM");
          // axios post request parameters
          const data = { ... }
          };
          const axiosConfig = {
            headers: { ... }
          };
          const contactAxiosUrl = "...";
          // send axios post request
          const makeAxiosPostRequest = async (url, data, config) => {
            try {
              const result = await axios.post(url, data, config);
              console.log("axios post request result: ", result);
              return true;
            } catch (err) {
              console.log("axios post request: ", err.message);
              return false;
            }
          };
          this.$store.dispatch("switchLoading", true);
          const sent = await makeAxiosPostRequest( contactAxiosUrl, contactAxiosData, axiosConfig );
          this.$store.dispatch("switchLoading", false);
          return sent;
        } else {
          console.log("INVALID FORM");
          return false;
        }
      };
      const result = validateAndSend();
      console.log("RESULT: ", result);
    },

the console log is :

    SUBMIT !
    app.js:3312 RESULT:  Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promisecatch: ƒ catch()constructor: ƒ Promise()finally: ƒ finally()then: ƒ then()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 2name: "then"__proto__: ƒ ()[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"__proto__: Object[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: false
    app.js:3209 form validated... isValid:  false
    app.js:3291 INVALID FORM
```

I should normally get :

```
 SUBMIT !
 form validated... isValid:  false
 INVALID FORM
```

and finally

```
 RESULT
```

What's wrong with my nested awaut/sync...
thnaks for feedback

Comment: You need await before validateAndSend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validateAndSend returns the promise instantly.

change:

```
const result = validateAndSend();
```

into:

```
const result = await validateAndSend();
```

*(and add `async` to the submitForm)*

To wait for the promise to complete before logging the result.

Comment: Adding await before validateAndSend() raises a syntax error :  await is a reserved word (158:21)...

Comment: my fault : I have also ( as you suggested ) to add async to the submitForm . SOLVED . I get now . SUBMIT !
app.js:3238 form validated... isValid:  false
app.js:3321 INVALID FORM
app.js:3346 RESULT:  false

Answer (score 0):

Remove makeValidationRequest function, it is unnecessary and wrong. Try this:

```
submitForm: async function () {
  // get form validation status
  let formIsValid = await this.$validator.validateAll()

  let url = ''
  let formData = {}
  let config = {
    headers: {}
  }

  const postData = async (url, dta, cnf) => {
    try {
      // first, show loader
      this.$store.dispatch('switchLoading', true)
      // then try to get response.data
      let {data} = await axios.post(url, dta, cnf)
      // if successful, just console it
      console.log(`form post successful: ${data}`)
    } catch (err) {
      // if unsuccessful, console it too
      console.log(`error posting data: ${err}`)
    } finally {
      // successful or not, always hide loader
      this.$store.dispatch('switchLoading', false)
    }
  }

  formIsValid && postData(url, formData, config)
  // else not required, you can't submit invalid form
}
```

Comment: Got it ... so simple